# Code RED tools for Scala

Tags: scala, jenkins-plugins, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd

I have been a Java developer and have been using code red tools like FindBugs, CheckStyle, PMD-CPD etc., I have integrated these plugin in Jenkins for automated reviews as well.

When I moved to scala, I want to continue with Maven and Jenkins. But I am not able to find code red tools supported in eclipse, maven-plugin & Jenkins plugins for Scala. Can anyone give some pointer to this to address the static code analysis, code coverage etc., ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many cool tools for integrated with scala, i provide list of tools preferred by me below:

- Scalastyle https://github.com/scalastyle/scalastyle
- Scapegoat https://github.com/sksamuel/scalac-scapegoat-plugin
- Wart remover https://github.com/typelevel/wartremover
- Linter https://github.com/HairyFotr/linter
- CPD https://github.com/sbt/cpd4sbt
- Abide https://github.com/scala/scala-abide

**UPD**
Firstly, for integration between scala and jenkins you must use sbt plugin in jenkins. Secondly, there are several useful plugins for code quality in jenkins (`scapegoat`, see link above, it's flexible for your case wiht scala and jenkins), `scoverage`plugin https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Scoverage+Plugin for code coverage metrics and of course own commands of sbt, they are very helpful, like `sbt doc, sbt test`. I found nice article about jenkins and scala http://yeghishe.github.io/2015/02/28/continuous-integration-for-scala-projects.html

Comment: Thanks Art_Rebel for a prompt response. Just did a quick analysis, these tools are awesome with sbt or standalone but not going well with jenkins. What do think it is going to be? Is it going to be Jenkins adapting all Scala related stuffs? or Is it going to be SBT evolving for Scala?

Comment: @Scott Shipp thx for comment, i appended scoverage under UPD section

Comment: @Ashok Krishnamoorthy Did it clarify the situation?

Comment: Yes it clarified. Now setting up the environment specific to scala coming out from java thinking. Thanks.